# If we know the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$, can we say anything about the prime factorization of $a + b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know we can say if $a$ and $b$ have a common factor, then that factor is also in $a+b$. But my guess is we can't say much more than this. Is it even possible that the factors of $a$ and $b$ completely determine the factors of $a+b$? Would finding such a relationship solve most open questions and be equivalent to finding a formula for finding primes?

Sorry if the last part is too opinion basd, i can edit it down if needed.

Comment: The factors of $a$ and $b$ absolutely completely determine the factors of $a+b$. If you have the factors, you have the numbers. Add them and factorize. If that doesn't answer your question, then you probably need to be more precise.

Comment: @MattSamuel I mean can we say anything about the factors of $a+b$ without actually finding the sum $a+b$ and factoring it.

Comment: What part of finding the sum and factoring it do you want to forbid? Do you have even a single suggestion? I can't decide whether this is too broad or unclear now, but it's certainly unanswerable.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm not yet sure how to make this more precise, but I hope that at least I can convey what I mean: I am looking for a function which takes as input the prime factors of $a$ and $b$ and gives as output the prime factors of $a+b$; this function should not amount to just adding the numbers and factoring the result "in disguise" (As an example, there are many formulas known today that give the $n^{th}$ prime, but they are worthless because they take as input an integer, and "in disguise" they check if it has divisors)

Answer (score 3):

Whenever $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, the factors of $a+b$ can be *anything*.

For instance, in this case there will be infinitely many primes of the form $a+nb$ (Dirichlet's theorem), so there's no way this factorization can be determined.

So, I think in general the answer to your question is **no** (it's true of course for trivial cases like $a = nb$).

Comment: Has it been proven that it's impossible to determine the factors of $a+b$, or is it possible that we haven't figured out the formula yet?

Comment: I think I don't have the knowledge to answer that, but my opinion is that it is impossible. Again, if it were possible for all $a$, $b$, then you could generate infinitely many primes (not sure if this is a contradiction). One thing, if you take $b=1$ then this is definitively false: the factors of $a$ do not determine *all* the factors of $a+1$

Comment: Oh, of course, there's not a contradiction by generating infinitely many primes (think on Euclid's proof of infiniteness of primes)

Comment: @ovi & Solid Snake : there is also a problem of information. The relatively primes context doesn't provide enough information to build a solution that may be usable with the same algorithm for any pair. Otherwise, this algorithm will need to cointain a lot of external datas to be efficient, for example, the primes sequences of any integer. I'll expand if I see a similar question based on the capacity to build a solution with the input data.

Comment: Your "guess" in your question as well as the answer given by @Solid Snake, do make sense. Because if one could say something about the divisors of a + b without actually finding the sum, this would give an elementary attack of FLT, wouldn't it ?

Comment: If I can suggest a little elaboration of your lead sentence, if $a,b$ are relatively prime, the factors of $a+b$ can be anything *relatively prime to both* $a$ and $b$.  We could even prove a more precise version of such a proposition.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can say a little bit.  We at least know that any prime-power that divides both $a$ and $b$ will divide $a+b$.  And we know that any prime-power that divides exactly one of $a$ and $b$ can not divide $a+b$.  Given factorizations of $a$ and $b$, we know some prime-powers that definitely are and some that definitely are not in the factorization of $a+b$.

In fact, this is the idea behind Mersenne and Fermat primes.  And the search for primes of the form $n! \pm 1$.  We grab a number with lots of small prime factors and add one, knowing that the result won't have any of those small prime factors and so we have a better chance of getting a prime.

Answer (score 2):

The **abc conjecture** states

> Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $(a,b,c)$ be a triple of coprime positive integers such that $a+b=c$. Calling $P$ the product of the distinct prime factors of $abc$, we have $c>P^{1+\varepsilon}$ only for *finitely many* $(a,b,c).$

In other words, it appears that usually $c$ has relatively small (or few) prime factors. Shinichi Mochizuki developed a brand new theory within four long papers on which he claims to have proved the conjecture. Recently, a handful of mathematicians [have announced](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2099534-mathematicians-finally-starting-to-understand-epic-abc-proof/) they are going through his work.

Comment: Do you have the source for mathematicians going through his work?

Comment: @Ovi: Yes, I'm adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [abc conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) says that if $a$ and $b$ are composed of prime factors with large multiplicity, then $a+b$ can't also be composed of prime factors with large multiplicity.

Comment: Except for finitely many cases, right? I don't quite remember the abc conjecture exactly.

Comment: You are right in that the usual formulation of the $abc$ conjecture involves finitely many exceptions. But this also means that there exists a best abc triple. So you can just take "large" in the above answer as meaning larger than the best triple.